# MySQL - querying tables on different databases/hostnames

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Good morning!

I have 2 tables that are stored on different databases - different mySQL hostnames.

How to I join them?

Is there a way to open a connection to a database, being connected to another, using commands at the MYSQL Workbench GUI interface (not command prompt) and then query it?

Many thanks,

Comment: FEDERATED Engine may help if available.

Comment: Sounds more like a dba question to me